# Modelling Tennis as markov chain with unkown server

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Assume that we model a game in tennis as follows:
if player A serves, they have a probability of holding their service (win a point) pA and player B, a probability pB.

The idea is assuming A serves:

```
p(0,0) =  1  (before match starts)
p(1,0) = pA * p(0,0) 
p(0,1) = (1-pA) * p(0,0)
p(1,1) = pA * p(0,1) + (1-pA) * p(1,0)
p(2,0) = pA * p(1,0)
```

etc

same notation for player B.

Here is my question to you: I have two methodologies for figuring out the probability of player A or B winning the game if we don't know who serves (the derive different results) and I am not sure which one is correct:

**Method 1**

I derive my probabilities assuming player A serves -> table 1
I derive my probabilities assuming player B server -> table 2

my desirable table of probs is the average `(table1 + table 2)/2` and `player A winning is = p(4,0) + p(4,1) + p(4,2) + p(win by advantage)`

**Method 2**

Player A has an probability pA if servers and (1-pB) if receives, hence
overall probability `(pA + (1-pB))/2 = pC`

and now I model a game using pC

These two methods return different results

### Example

- Method 1
  pA = 0.65
  pB = 0.60

  A winning 4-0 as server : p(4,0) = pA^4 = 0.65^4 = 0.1758
  A winning 4-0 as receiver: p(4,0) = (1-pB)^4 = 0.0256

  A winning 4-0 on average: **0.1020**
- Method 2

  pC = (0.65 + (1-0.60))/2 = 0.525

  A winning 4-0 on average: p(4,0) = 0.525 ^ 4 = **0.0757**

Comment: Method $1$ is correct.  Method $2$ doesn't make any sense; I don't know what else to say about it.

Comment: Agree but i need a proof. Thanks